# Ubuntu server networking issue, can't see other computers on network

Tags: networking, server

I have an Ubuntu 14 server that I've set the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
   address 192.168.1.15
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

`ifconfig` shows:
everything as normal and I have lights on my network interface as well as front of server showing activity.

`route -n` also shows correctly.

However, I can not ping anything on the network nor can I ping this server from another box.  it is like I have a bad cable but I've tried multiple cables, even swapped out entire server hardware by moving hard drive to another box.  I've setup 30+ servers over the years and I have NEVER seen anything like this.

I've also shut down firewall and all other services that might effect network to see if any were causing the problem.  At the moment it is like this server is not plugged into the network at all even though it is.

Oh, lastly, I have other boxes plugged into same cisco router and they all work fine.  I also tried moving ports on router just to make sure and that didn't help.

Anyone have any ideas of what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Is there a DHCP server on the network? if so, are you sure that `192.168.1.15` is outside of its DHCP address pool?

Comment: Show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Edit that output into your question please. Report back to @heynnema